# I'm putting my entire $_SESSION variable into a json object on page load. While this works for me, is this a good practice?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I've been doing something this at the bottom of all my views:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$.post('php/ajax.php', {type:'session'}).done(function(data){
     var session = JSON.parse(data);
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getScript('resources/redactor/redactor.js');
        $.getScript('javascript/year_long_calendar.js');
        $.getScript('javascript/edit_lesson_modal.js');
     });
 });
</script>
```

This works really well for me. All my scripts get loaded inside of a single docReady, and all my ajax requires a token that gets generated upon login and stored in $_SESSION. This stops people from hitting my ajax logic using fake headers. By doing this, my ajax calls look something like:

```
$.post(url:'ajax.php', {token:session.token, id:id}).done(function(data){ ... });
```

I can also access other session variables

```
var user_id = session.user_id;
```

Since I've been doing this from the start of the project, I intentionally keep any sensitive information like passwords out of the session variable. What are your thoughts on this? Does any of this strike you as insecure, or terribly inefficient? I realize $.getScript is often used as a lazy way to load libraries, but I think I've found a pretty valid use for it.

None of the data in $_SESSION is sensitive except the token, and you have to be logged in to get one. Unless someone malicious hops on a machine while the real user is away and knows exactly where my ajax logic is, how it works, how I store my session, and fakes a quick header on PostMan to delete all my tables, I don't see it being an issue.

EDIT:
@AnotherGuy helped me realize a much better solution. My ajax.php file now looks like this:

```
<?php session_start();
include('connect.php');
include('functions.php');

// check to see if http request is ajax (easy to fake but hey might as well)
if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest'){

    // when the user logs in, a random number is generated and saved to $_SESSION['token'].
    // this block is used to pass the token to a javascript variable securely
    if($_POST['type'] == 'session'){
        $session = [
            'token'=>$_SESSION['token'],
            'user_id'=>$_SESSION['user_id']
        ];
        echo json_encode($session);
    }

    // all post requests must pass the correct token variable to step into this block and access the ajax logic
    if(isset($_POST['token']) && $_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token']){


        if($_POST['type'] == 'get'){
            $where = null;
            if(isset($_POST['where'])){
                $where = json_decode($_POST['where']);
            }
            $order_by = null;
            if(isset($_POST['order_by'])){
                $order_by = json_decode($_POST['order_by']);
            }
            echo json_encode(get($_POST['db'], $_POST['table'], $where, $order_by)->fetchAll());
        }

        if($_POST['type'] == 'put'){
            $set = json_decode($_POST['set']);
            echo put($_POST['db'], $_POST['table'], $set);
        }

        if($_POST['type'] == 'update'){
            $set = json_decode($_POST['set']);
            $where = json_decode($_POST['where']);
            update($_POST['db'], $_POST['table'], $set, $where);
        }

        if($_POST['type'] == 'delete'){
            $where = json_decode($_POST['where']);
            delete($_POST['db'], $_POST['from'], $where);
        }
```

Comment: Consider that in the future, sensitive info may be stored in the session. Any reason why you need to access all session data from your JS? Wouldn't it be better to selectively provide this information?

Comment: Yup! I updated my ajax logic to do just that. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

From how you describe you are using the session I cannot see any harm in it, but I still think it is dangerous. Imagine you in the future work on another project and then come back to this. Will you still remember not to store any sensitive information inside the session? As a basic rule of thumb is to never store sensitive information in the session unless it is the only solution, which it rarely is. But sometimes mistakes are made and they can hurt you!

I would change this to something that looks/works in the same way, but offers you more decoupling from the session. If you are fetching the entire session you are bound to retrieve some information which would never be used or should never be available to client side (through Javascript). I would create a single page that you request which can only provide the necessary information. That way you can also ensure only required information is exposed to the client side.

So instead of requesting a generic `ajax.php` file, I would create a page called (or something like it) `userInfo.php`. That way you can also eliminate the `type` variable you send along with it.

Hope this can help you, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You could store that session data in browser with `sesssionStorage` in a serialized JSON string and manipulate it from there. Many recommend this approach over using cookies [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Cheers.